# Laravel populate form with DB data but showing all users data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I read this [Populating a dropdown menu with database results in Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937116/populating-a-dropdown-menu-with-database-results-in-laravel-4)

and was able to populate a select grabbing values from the MySQL database in Laravel
However, this is not being restricted to the data belonging to the logged-in user.
Any hits appreciated
`Route::get('applications', array('before' => 'auth', function()
         {
            //return View::make('applications');  //commented out 10/31/15

```
      // 10/31/15 create the array to hold companies from companies table - $company_lists

      //return view applications plus the array

      $company_lists = Company::lists('company', 'id');  /// 10/31/
       $resume_lists = Resume::lists('name', 'user_id');  /// 11/1/15


      return View::make('applications', array('company_lists' => $company_lists), array('resume_lists' => $resume_lists));  ///10/31/15
    }
)
```

);`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing where clauses. I don't quite get your table structure, so not entirely which bits require the where clauses, but I imagine something along these lines would work better:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$resume_lists = Resume::where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->lists('name', 'user_id');
```

Comment: are you sure you can use the where clause in there?

Comment: Pretty sure, this is in the docs: `$model = User::where('votes', '>', 100)->get();` Still laravel has some funny interactions, maybe it doesn't like 'lists'